# Erro com app Flask Babel Python3 (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, flask

Estou seguindo o tutorial do artigo
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms/page/3#comments

Cheguei na parte III e deu esse erro.

Eu estou confuso porque o autor manda executar o `run.py` dentro da pasta Script do virtualenv.

Sendo que ele manda criar o `run.py` na raiz.

Mas penso que o problema nao seja isso, por isso preciso de ajuda.

[image: Erro no flask]

Ao seguir a ajuda do @sergiopereira (excluir o babel) e reinstalar pelo gitHub esta dando o seguinte erro.
[image: Erro da imagem]

Para acertar esse erro é preciso o Git nas variaveis de ambiente do Windows.
http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade o autor manda executar **o script** *run.py*, nada sobre nenhuma pasta Script.

Você está usando Python 3 ou 2? Há um [bug no Babel](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel/issues/174) com Python 3.

Uma das sugestões é desinstalar o Babel e instalar de novo via GitHub (ou mudar seu projeto para Python 2.7):

```
pip unistall babel
pip install git+https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel.git@2.0
```

Comment: para instalar via gitHub na virtualenv não funciona dessa maneira?

Comment: Deveria funcionar. Todos esses comandos devem ser executados no seu virtualenv. Deu algum erro?

Comment: deu o seguinte erro: `Error [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado while executing command git clone -q https://github[...]. Cannot find command 'git'`

Estou usando python 3 e windows 10.

Comment: Segue a imagem do erro:

Comment: Imagem esta acima, na descrição do problema.

Comment: Ja encontrei o erro. Eu não tinha colocado o Git nas variaveis de ambiente do Windows.